# Debugging Android SDK libraries

Tags: java, android, c, debugging, android-source

I would now like a way to step through the SDK libraries (both C and Java code) to pinpoint exactly what is going on. So far, I have installed the NDK and gotten GDB up and running.  I am able to attach to the process.  I've tried `bt` and `strace` but that doesn't provide any useful information.

1. What do I need to do to be able to step into the Java code from the SDK (and the native C code if it comes to that) and go line by line through the code?
2. Is there a way that GDB can be used to provide more useful information?

Comment: Assuming your Java implementation translated from Java straight to ARM machine code, where is the "native C code"?

Comment: libc.so - You bring up a good point though, there may be another Java layer between the native code.  Do I need to download the source for that too, or are there pre-compiled debug symbols somewhere in the SDK?

Comment: I think you're confused. C isn't some kind of assembly; It was developed for the same reason that Java was developed: So that programmers can write portable code that compiles and behaves identically on a variety of systems, rather than writing a variety of assembly ports of a program. Your Java VM most likely assembles to your machine code dialect, not C.

Comment: libc.so is machine code, not C.

Comment: I don't think my question is clear.  I am not looking to debug *my* code.  I am looking to debug the SDKs that came with Android so I can better understand why the errors are occurring.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace that you can share with us?

Comment: @HeatfanJon Is there a preferred way to get the stack trace?  I'll put together a paste bin of what I've been able to grab so far.

Comment: @BrianV Please describe your errors and provide relevant names of classes/functions so that we may help you find the manual(s) that'll tell you *why the errors are occuring*.

Comment: I am getting two errors, which are related to the same functionality.  I am using the USB libraries.  Depending on whether the device is connected when I start the app, I get  two different signal  errors. I don't get any useful information other than the signal names.  The actual errors aren't really relevant to my question ( I don't think) so I've listen them here: http://pastebin.com/4DgxBuGD

Comment: Perhaps you're providing a Java object to the C library, and the Java garbage collector is moving that object while the C function is operating. I can't give more than a guess without code for the invocation of the C library, and any relevant objects passed to the C library.

Answer (score 1):

Android is multi process UI framework with different parties communicating over binder.
As an sdk developer, you should be able to step into client side Java sources if you attach the source jar to your ADT project when prompted. 
If you want to debug JNI code of your app, you can use NDK debugging tools.
If you want to go below these layers or debug multiple processes, it gets tricky.

Please check [Debugging native libs of Android Java apps](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/07/debugging-native-framework-code-of.html) article to understand stepping into client side  native framework libraries.

If you want to debug Java code of system_server (the process that hosts core framework services), please check [Debugging Android Java framework services](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/debugging-android-java-framework.html) article.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to partially answer my question, unfortunately the answer isn't an easy one.

**Debugging Java**

To debug the Java source you need to grab the source code for Android itself.  That is located here: `source.android.com`.  There are instructions provided there on how to download the source.  The instructions claim you'll need to do the steps on OSX or Linux, though it may be possible to use Cygwin.  As noted [here](http://blog.michael-forster.de/2008/12/view-android-source-code-in-eclipse.html), the files aren't in one consistent location. I used the [python script](http://pastebin.com/Anreer3B) provided on the previously mentioned page to generate a zip file of the source.  Once you have the Java files in one place, all you have to do is point Eclipse towards those files when you step into compiled Java code.

**Debugging Native**

I am still working on this part, so far I am able to connect to my app using GDB from Cygwin but have yet to actually step into the native C files.  Presumably, the libraries will need to be built in debug mode.